# using ajax from a php function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am new with ajax. I have this php function already from `functions.php`

```
function checkUserEmailExistent($email){
   ...
   return $boolean;
}
```

and this is for my views `views.html`

`<input type='text' name='email' id='email'>`

this is for the `script.js`

```
jQuery( "#email" ).blur(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'value' : $(this).val() },
            success : function(result){

            }
        });
    });
```

my issue is how can I call my php function in ajax to connect it to my html. when it `blur` it check the email value if it is exist or not.

Comment: just create a new php file which will receive your json data from POST array, call you method providing its received value and return a result.

Comment: Within your ajax function `url : path_to_controller/checkUserEmailExistent`

Comment: check this example it will help you  https://beski.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/check-email-already-exist-ajax-jquery/

Comment: Put your entire javascript in `$(document).ready(function(){"Your code here"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

work in WordPress

JS SCRIPT

```
jQuery( "#email" ).blur(function() {
    jQuery.ajax(
                    {
                        url: ajax_url,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            action: 'checkUserEmailExistent',
                            email: $(this).val(),
                        },
                        async: false,
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            if (data.validation == 'true')
                                jQuery('.email-massage').html('<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><strong>Success!</strong>  successfully</div>');
                            else
                                jQuery('.email-massage').html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><strong>Oops!</strong> Something went wrong.</div>');

                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                        {
                            jQuery('.email-massage').html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><strong>Oops!</strong> Something went wrong.</div>');
                        }
                    });
});
```

WP SCRIPT in functions.php

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_checkUserEmailExistent', 'checkUserEmailExistent');
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_checkUserEmailExistent', 'checkUserEmailExistent');

        function checkUserEmailExistent() {
        $email = $_POST['email']; // get email val
        /*if() your condition
$email = 1;
else
$email = 0;
*/

    if ($email == 1):
                $email_val= 'true';
            else:
                $email_val = 'false';
            endif;
            echo json_encode(array("validation" => $email_val));
            die;
    }
```

in function.php Enqueue file after add this code like this

```
wp_enqueue_script('themeslug-default', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/default.js', array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script('themeslug-default', 'ajax_url', admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));
```

Comment: what shoul be the value of `ajax_url` then?

Comment: what is the `'admin-ajax.php'` ?

Comment: now I get it.. but I always get an error on ajax, it always return to false. so I tried to `alert(data + ' | '+ data.validation);` inside the script.. and I got `0 | undifined`? please help me.. thanks in advancs

Comment: I also put `wp_die()` at the end of my php function but still I got `0` on the ajax `data`

Comment: you give me live URL so i will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Set url to the php file where you have checkUserEmailExistent function. Then:

```
function checkUserEmailExistent($email){
   ...
   return $boolean;
}
 return checkUserEmailExistent($_REQUEST['value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I give the example for validation.This will help you to check

```
Email id<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size=18 maxlength=50  onblur="javascript:myFunction(this.value)">
```

You need to add the script

```
  <script>
   function myFunction(em) {
if(em!='')
{   

  var x = document.getElementById("email").value;

   var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
   document.getElementById("email").value = "";
  return false;
  exit();
  }   
           var email=$("#email").val();

  $.ajax({
type:'post',
    url:'email_client.php',
    data:{email: email},
    success:function(msg){
 if (msg.length> 0) {
alert(msg);
document.getElementById("email").value = "";
 }
 }
        });


     }          }
               </script>
```

Create a page 'email_client.php' and add the code

```
 <?php
  $s=$_POST['email'];
  include "config.php";
$echeck="select email from client where active=0 and       email='".$_POST['email']."'";  //change your query as you needed
  $echk=mysql_query($echeck);
  $ecount=mysql_num_rows($echk);

   if($ecount>='1' && $s!='0')
    {
   echo "Email already exists";
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't call your server function inside Ajax you only send your data in JSON format  to the server on getting this data,server will route(if MVC) it to specific function and return a response to client in JSON format so now inside Ajax you perform operation on success (what to do next ) and in case of failure show the error

How server will route it to specific function that depend on framework you use, but i think they simply use regexp to match with URL

Answer (score 0):

You would call it in your `url` parameter. However, you'll need to manage your AJAX handler in the PHP script.

**AJAX**

```
jQuery( "#email" ).blur(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'functions.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'value' : $(this).val() },
        success : function(result){
            if (result.success) {
                //handle success//
            } else if (result.failure) {
                //handle failure//
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
function checkUserEmailExistent($email){
   ...
   return $boolean;
}

if ($_POST['value']) {
    $status = checkUserEmailExistent($email);
    if ($status === true) {
        echo json_encode (array('status' => 'success'));
    } elseif ($status === false) {
        echo json_encode (array('status' => 'failure'));
    }
}
```